# how to get inverse matrix by using alglib rmatrixinverse

Tags: c++

I would like to ask one simply question about rmatrixinverse() from alglib. I got a 2D double array named `M (matrix n*n)` and I want to get the inverse matrix named `invM`. I am, for this case, using rmatrixinverse(), but the result is wrong. I tried some of the other inverse matrix solvers from alglib as well, but in my opinion, `rmatrixinverse()` fits the best, since the data is full of doubles.

If someone ever faced this problem and have any idea, I will be very thankful.

```
alglib::real_2d_array invMalglib;
alglib::ae_int_t info;
alglib::matinvreport rep;
invMalglib.setlength(matrix_degree,matrix_degree);
for(int i = 0; i < matrix_degree; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < matrix_degree; j++)
        invMalglib[i][j] = M[i][j];

vector_from_matrix_and_vector(F, X, FtX, small_length, matrix_degree);
alglib::rmatrixinverse(invMalglib, info, rep);
for(int i = 0; i < matrix_degree; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < matrix_degree; j++)
        invM[i][j] = invMalglib[i][j];
```

Comment: plese edit your question, remember that code must be indented with 4 spaces. And about your question, I warmly suggest you to use Eigen for your matrix computations:

eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page

Comment: My first time here, so I apologize for the code alignment. And I want to thank you for the hint of using Eigen. I am going to see that.

Comment: It's one of the most useful libraries out there and has no dependendencies, being header only library. It has a very very good documentation and is used in many current project.

Comment: I am reading the getting started guide right now to learn how to use it properly. And, in fact, it seems to be very useful "tool".

Comment: **(1)** " ... but the result is wrong." : is the result in any way close to the correct answer? **(2)** Is the matrix `M` sparse or non-sparse? You appear to be unsure as to the appropriate alglib function to call. **(3)** What is the condition number returned within the `matinvreport` structure? If it is too high the computation is not feasible. **(4)** I assume the function call `vector_from_matrix_and_vector` with arguments `F`, `X`, `FtX` is unrelated to `invMalglib` and `M`? **(5)** The assignment `invMalglib` to `invM` appears to be redundant.

Comment: **damienh** In order your questions were asked. **(1)** The result is absolutely different. **(2)** The matrix is non-sparse and I am quite unsure, but from the specifications, used function rmatrixinverse fits for the biggest set of the matrices as a universal solver. http://www.alglib.net/translator/man/manual.cpp.html#sub_rmatrixinverse But this was also part of my question. **(3)** I have not checked the condition number yet. **(4)** vector_from_matrix_and_vector() is not related to invM, M and invMalglib, this was only part of the code + variables at the top.

Comment: **(5)** This assignment seems to be redundant, but needed for the other part of the code.